# How do I extract the elements from a container file (ODP, PDF, etc)?

Tags: pdf, extract, container

PDF and other container file types like ODP contain several files glued together to a presentation / a document. Is there a way to separate these files after the container has been built? Like from a zip file?

I just wonder because since you can edit these container files afterwards, the elements must be stored separately somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know for sure that it is possible to extract images and other content from an MS Word document (`.docx`) by opening  it with an archive file manager such as `7zip` and navigating through the directories.

I am not sure about PDFs and ODPs, but try opening such a file with 7zip and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't thinking about simply opening it with an unzipper

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, unzipping via the Finder sometimes doesn't work. Then you get a file that ends with `.zip.cpgz`, after first renaming the `.odp` file to `.zip`. I ended up using the terminal command unzip. Before you do this, put the file inside an empty folder, because all files and folders end up in the folder.

```
mv filename.odp filename.zip
unzip filename.zip -d content
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @SPRBRN's answer, with the ODP format you can extract it directly from the file to a directory:

```
unzip filename.odp -d unpacked
```

This is not so easy with PDF for which there is a tool **pdfimages** from the **poppler** package.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I rename the file extension from ".odp" to ".zip", and then use a file extractor like 7zip.